# POSIX Shared memory

Tags: posix, shared-memory

what is the difference between:

1. shm_open("test")
2. mmap()
3. close()
4. munmap()
5. shm_unlink()

and:

1. open("/dev/shm/test")
2. mmap()
3. close()
4. munmap()
5. unlink()

The only difference I see is that the second options does not need to link with `-lrt`

Comment: you really should improve the question...

Comment: The difference is `shm_open` is POSIX, while `tmpfs` on `/dev/shm` is a non-portable way to *realize* `shm_open`.

Comment: Ok thank you. So there no performance difference between both.

Comment: @Kouros As there is no guarantee that the former is implemented as the latter, I can't say for sure. In practice, the performance difference is negible. Benchmark to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same thing except that `shm_open(test)` is POSIX standard and needs the `librt` library, and `open(/dev/shm/test)` is not POSIX standard and does not need the `librt` library. Performance is equal for both solution.